# Laravel, chamar a Action de um Controller a partir de uma View?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tenho uma `View` onde dentro dela eu gostaria de adicionar o link de um `Controller` com sua `Action` especifica e ao carregar esta `View` a `Action` desse `Controller` seja acionada.

**Exemplo:** dentro de uma `View` eu tenho uma chamada de `controller` `Home@index` que quando essa action é chamada irá renderizar a `View` dessa `Action`.

Comment: A sua duvida está ocasionando novas! Você está querendo trabalhar com ajax? ou você está querendo carregar uma View dentro da outro pelo Action? se poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/215835/edit) e tentar explicar mais detalhado, não ficou muito claro

Comment: Estou querendo carregar uma view dentro da outra pelo action

Comment: Poste essa View? com essa chamada! Porque assim com `@include` já resolveria, então preciso saber o que realmente você está querendo.

Comment: É quase isso, mas acho que a tecnologia ainda não existe no laravel.
Quando eu programava em ASP.NET eu tinha uma Helpers no Razor que é a Engine Template do ASP.NET que gerava uma view parcial pra mim, onde ele chamava ela a partir de uma action de um controller.

Eu estou querendo fazer a mesma coisa no Laravel, mas acho que não tem como ainda =/

Comment: Entendi acho que não tem mas vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Desde já eu agradeço muito toda cooperação!

Comment: Coloque uma nova edição com um `blade` criado... bem parecido com que você disse no asp.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem nada pronto pelo que pude conferir, mas, existem maneiras de executar:

***Exemplo minimo***

*`Controller`*

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SortController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('sort');
    }

    public function trecho(Request $request)
    {
        $url = $request->fullUrl();
        return view('trecho', ['url' => $url]);
    }
}
```

*`Routes.php`*

```
Route::get('/sort', ['as' => 'sort.index', 'uses' => 'SortController@index']);
Route::get('/sort/trecho', ['as' => 'sort.trecho', 'uses' => 'SortController@trecho']);
```

*`View` sort*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">        
    <title>View Sort</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sort</h1>
    {!! app(App\Http\Controllers\SortController::class)->trecho(app('request')) !!}
</body>
</html>
```

No `controller` existem dois métodos um que vai iniciar e o outro que vai ser chamado pela `View` `sort.blade.php`. Na sua `View` chame o comando:

```
{!! app(App\Http\Controllers\SortController::class)->trecho(app('request')) !!}
```

que a execução fará o seu papel em trazer a `View` gerada.

---

Pode ser gerado também um `blade extension` da seguinte maneira, abra o arquivo `app\Providers\ServiceProvider.php` e importe o `namespace`: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;` e dentro do método `boot` adicione a seguinte código para criar um novo `blade` para seu projeto:

```
public function boot()
{   
    Blade::directive('action', function($expression) {
        $vars = explode(',', $expression);
        $ctrl_string = trim(array_shift($vars));
        $meth_string = trim(array_shift($vars));
        $ctrl = app($ctrl_string);
        $items = array_map(function ($var){
            return eval("return $var;");
        }, $vars);
        $view  = (is_array($items) && count($items) > 0)
                ? call_user_func_array(array($ctrl, $meth_string), $items)
                : call_user_func(array($ctrl, $meth_string));
        return "<?php echo '".$view."'; ?>";
    });
}
```

Na `View` chame da seguinte forma:

```
@action(App\Http\Controllers\SortController,trecho,app('request'))
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#rendering-views-for-collections)
- [Blade Templates - Extending A Layout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-a-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma que constantemente uso em meus testes são através dos **Helpers** do próprio Laravel.

Usarei como exemplo essa rota no arquivo routes\web.php:

```
Route::get('/diretorio','Seucontroller@action')->name('rota.teste');
```

Para chamar o controlador durante uma view qualquer você simplesmente poderia fazer o seguinte na view realizar a chamada :

```
<a href="{{route('rota.teste')}}"> Link de teste </a>
```

[Uso de helpers do laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers)